# Does .remove on a document object result in a null?

Tags: java, ibm-domino

In my java webagent I create a Document object.
For example 
NotesDocument document = ...;
later I use remove on this object:

```
document.remove(true);
```

Afterwards I want to check if document is null so any functions which normally operates on that document will not be executed

for example:

```
if(document != null){
System.out.println(document.getItemValueString("ID"));
}
```

It still goes into the if statement and its saying: NotesException: Object has been removed or recycled.

Is != null functioning in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already created a reference in the memory here.

```
NotesDocument document = ...;

...

// Even you called document.remove(), it still exists because the code does not destroy the object and reference itself.

document.remove(true);

// That is why this still works.
if (document != null) {
    System.out.println(document.getItemValueString("ID"));
}
```

You can explicitly assign `document = null;` after you call `remove()` if that is what you are designated to do.

Or

You can check isDeleted() of document. e.g. `if (!document.isDeleted())`.

Doc:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_9.0.1/reference/r_domino_Document_IsDeleted.html